# Is there a way to test Postgresql connection from VMware Fusion on a Mac?

Tags: macos, postgresql, vmware-fusion

I have some reasons to believe that VMware Fusion is not connecting to my postgresql database hosted on my Mac OS.

Is there a way to test this connection from my Windows portion through VMware?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, this can work. Are you running into a specific problem?

Check your network connection in VMware Fusion...

[image]

If it's Bridged, you should be able to use (allow) the IP address of the VM and your Mac. If NAT, you'll need to use the NAT'ed IP.

If you're set to NAT, running `ifconfig` on the Mac will show you the Mac's host networking address...

```
vmnet8: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 00:50:56:c0:00:08
    inet 192.168.94.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.94.255
```

Comment: I'm running a Rails app on my mac and trying to test it through vmware fusion. Except I see in the logs no DB connections are being made, and consequentially the site is not loading. I have some suspicions to believe that windows is not connecting. ----- I am connected via NAT. And I do see the networking address under `ifconfig`, but that's on the mac side. Does that mean that windows has that connection? should I add that IP to my pg_hba.conf or my postgresql.conf files? Right now I have `host    all             all             all                     trust` in pg_hba.conf

Comment: I should add that that my server is *responding*, but its postgresql database is not.

Comment: The NAT address can change. You may want Bridged anyway. But yes, you'll need to allow whatever address in your postgres access configuration files (and restart the service)

Comment: Wouldn't `all` cover any/all types of IP's?

Comment: Sorry for inundating you with this carpet bomb of questions. But another misc. one I had was.. the number after the `/` in the pg_hba.conf ip addresses ( ex. `127.0.0.1/32` ), what does that `32` mean? Is that the port? If so, when do `ifconfig` like your example is, what would the number after the `/` be? This is.. assuming I can't just write `all`.

Comment: @Trip, see [How does IPv4 Subnetting Work](http://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work) for the details of CIDR addressing.